# Node selection and replacement

Tags: xml, powershell

```xml
<XMLFile>
  <Pattern Pattern="1">
    <ID1>10</ID1>
    <ID2>2</ID2>
    <ID3>01_1</ID3>
    <ID4>01_1_SOTR_SOTR</ID4>
    <ID5>O</ID5>
   </Pattern>
</XMLFile>
```

I am trying to search an XML File for a set of conditions.  In this situation, I am looking for `ID1 = 10`, and whenever I find an `ID1 = 10`, I need to change `ID5` from a `O` to an `L`.  (I also have a few hundred of these node blocks to change by the way).

So I can search for my condition with the following:

```psh
$_XMLFile = [xml] (Get-Content $_XMLFilePath)

$nodes = $_XMLFile.XMLFile.Pattern | % {$_.ID1 -eq '10'} |
         Select-Object -Property ID5
```

What I am having issue with is changing `ID5`, once I have that list of nodes.

I have tried

```psh
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    $nodes | % {$_.ID5 -replace "O", "L"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using XPath to find the list of nodes?

```
$xmlDoc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XMLDocument
$xmlDoc.Load($fileName)
[System.Xml.XmlNodeList]$nodeList = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('XMLFile/Pattern[ID1=10]/ID5')
foreach ($node in $nodeList) {
    $node.'#text' = 'L'
}

$xmlDoc.Save($newFileName)
```